# When do I need to add client nodes and when do I only need server nodes?

Tags: ignite

I need the Ignite cluster for caching (MongoDB for persistence), and the application connects through thin clients. In this case, can I just add server nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a cluster consisting only of server nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask, when is it necessary for me to add a client node?

Comment: Thick clients have a richer API, so if you want your client to deploy code or listen for events, you'd need to use one. As more functionality has been added to the thin client, there are fewer reasons to use thick clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned a lot from it.